# Как объединить ограничения CHECK в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть следующая таблица:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE LectureHalls
    (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    floor INTEGER CHECK (floor <= 4),
    classroom INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sc_unique_lectureHall UNIQUE (id, floor, classroom),
    CONSTRAINT sc_unique_lectureHall2 UNIQUE (floor, classroom);
    );
```

**Можно ли создать такое ограничение в sql чтобы при floor = 1 classroom > 0 and classroom <= 30 ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ограничение-проверка может ссылаться на несколько столбцов, в таком случае оно не связано с определённым столбцом, а представлено отдельным элементом в списке. Определения столбцов и такие определения ограничений можно переставлять в произвольном порядке.

Такое ограничение является ограничением таблицы.

[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) [документация](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/ddl-constraints#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE LectureHalls (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    floor INTEGER CHECK (floor <= 4),
    classroom INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CHECK (floor is null or floor != 1 or (floor = 1 and classroom > 0 and classroom <= 30))
);
```

Хочу добавить, что подобные проверки будут более уместными на стороне бизнес-логики, а не на стороне хранилища данных.

Comment: @Akina  отредактировал ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет применить ограничение на уровне бл, не думал в этой манере.